# List of files in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I have images and I want to load them to my appplication.
my_app/lib/... - here my source files
my_app/assets/images/... - here my images

I need to get list of files in assets/images/ and after that show some of them (according to other logic)
I'm trying this

```
final dir = Directory("assets/images/");
print(dir.existsSync());    // <---- it also print: false
var files = dir.listSync().toList();
files.forEach((e) => list.add(MyImageItem(e.path)));
```

The problem is: I recieve exception

```
FileSystemException: Directory listing failed, path = 'assets/images/'
(OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
```

I've tried different ways: assets/images/, images/, images and so on
My pubspec.yaml

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/images/
    - assets/
```

When I create Image directly all is fine

```
new Image(image: AssetImage("assets/images/cat.png"))
```

I knew that previously (month ago) each resource has to be declared in pubspec.yaml directly, but now assets/images/ is ok.
I can load file by direct path. Why I can't access a directory? How to get list of files in directory to get them from my code?

Comment: Assets are not a directory. See https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/services/AssetBundle-class.html

Comment: Ok, so how I have to solve my task?
I need folder "images" somewhere and I need to get list of files in that folder.
I tried AssetBundle also... working with files in flutter is contrintuitive to me...

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer  Ok, so how I have to solve my task?
I need folder "images" somewhere and I need to get list of files in that folder.
I tried AssetBundle also... working with files in flutter is contrintuitive to me...

Comment: Did you find a solution to this yet?

Comment: Zip the image folders and unzip them into mobile disk space when launching app. File list can be done in disk space.

Answer (score 2):

When you add files to your assets, it means that you already know their paths.
Store all the images paths in a list and access them whenever you need.

For example if you have 3 images in

your_app/assets/images/image1.jpg
your_app/assets/images/image2.jpg
your_app/assets/images/image3.jpg

create a list and store all of them like:

```
List<String> imagePaths = ['assets/images/image1.jpg', 'assets/images/image2.jpg', 'assets/images/image3.jpg'];
```

and for example if you want to access your first image, use

`AssetImage(imagePaths[0])`

Comment: Thanks, I know this way, but it is a huge mess. I need 5-10k images and I don't like hard-code them all (even with generating code). Also I want to add new images over the time.... So, I need exactly list of files (or assets, or something like this)

Comment: Storing 5-10k images inside your app's package is a terrible idea, you better think of another solution.

Comment: If you must you can use code generation to generate a dart file with constants for each file.

Comment: Storing 5-10k images calls for data base solution especially for mobile app. You should always think to make your app as small as possible as size without sacrificing functionality.

Answer (score 2):

I keep a json file inside assets which records the file tree of assets folder.

When file list is needed, I just read from the json file.

Such json file can be easily generated by code.

However, this does not solve your problem directly when u have 5-10k images.
Only one json file might be too large to read.

Images should be grouped and recorded in separated json files.