# How do I get an array/list filled with all the image paths I loaded as assets in Flutter?

Tags: image, flutter, assetbundle

I want to know if there is a way (with or without pubspec.yaml asset list) to read a directory where images will be stored, and create an array with all the paths to each image, so I can go through the array (say, with a FOR ) and create a gallery of photos. This with the purpose of being able to change, remove or add images from the directory without worrying about the paths being coded in assets.

I've read that I can use AssetBundle or RootBundle for this but I cant find any example doing so. Any help on this, even pointing me in a different approach, would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

EDIT: This got marked as a duplicate, but the question referenced as a duplicate is different in the sense that I need to scan a directory *automatically* , So I dont need to know any of the names of the files on the directory, I just want a way to read the directory (who's name I can know) and retrieve an array populated with the assets inside the directory.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flutter How to store and access files with AssetBundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50998573/flutter-how-to-store-and-access-files-with-assetbundle)

Comment: Wouldn't a record in a database be more appropriate for this? Like a document collection.

Comment: Did you try the `AssetManifest.json` approach? That's "an array populated with the assets in the directory".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is (or at least used to be - beware, it's an implementation detail) an asset called `AssetManifest.json`. You can load that asset first, and it contains details of the actual assets.

Comment: I found an example with AssetManifest and it seems to be working, thank you!