# Flutter: How to get a list of names of all images in 'assets' directory?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have 100 images that I need to display in a list. I don't want to hard code all names.

How can I get the names of the images?

I want to have code like this:

```
final List<String> imageNames = await WhatEver.getNamesOfImagesInAssetsDirectory();
final widgets = imageNames.map((fileName) => Image.asset('images/${fileName}.png')).toList()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get an array/list filled with all the image paths I loaded as assets in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56369100/how-do-i-get-an-array-list-filled-with-all-the-image-paths-i-loaded-as-assets-in)

Answer (score 75, accepted):

I've implemented the function below inside of a `StatefulWidget`

```dart
    Future _initImages() async {
      // >> To get paths you need these 2 lines
      final manifestContent = await rootBundle.loadString('AssetManifest.json');
    
      final Map<String, dynamic> manifestMap = json.decode(manifestContent);
      // >> To get paths you need these 2 lines

      final imagePaths = manifestMap.keys
          .where((String key) => key.contains('images/'))
          .where((String key) => key.contains('.svg'))
          .toList();
    
      setState(() {
        someImages = imagePaths;
      });
    }
```

`AssetManifest.json` contains all data about all assets that you add in `pubspec.yaml`

Comment: You can also use `final manifestContent = await rootBundle.loadString('AssetManifest.json');` instead of `DefaultAssetBundle` if you want to do this in a place where you don't have a `BuildContext`.

Comment: how to read and print image path from assets to console like

```
assets/image.jpg
assets/image2.jpg
```

Answer (score 8):

The 'AssetManifest.json' will soon be deprecated that will be replaced with 'AssetManifest.bin'.

However it's still undocumented I believe. If you're using a newer Flutter version (see the links for updates), there is an api to get the list of assets like so:

```
final assetManifest = await AssetManifest.loadFromAssetBundle(rootBundle);
// This returns a List<String> with all your images
final imageAssetsList = assetManifest.listAssets().where((string) => string.startsWith("assets/images/")).toList()
```

Tested on Flutter Channel stable, 3.10.6

Related links/github tracking:

[Speed up first asset load by encoding asset manifest in binary rather than JSON](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/113637)

[[tracking] Speed up asset manifest loading and parsing](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/117228)

Answer (score 1):

```
Future _initImages() async {
  // >> To get paths you need these 2 lines
  final manifestContent = await rootBundle.loadString('AssetManifest.json');

  final Map<String, dynamic> manifestMap = json.decode(manifestContent);
  // >> To get paths you need these 2 lines

  final imagePaths = manifestMap.keys
      .where((String key) => key.contains('images/'))
      .where((String key) => key.contains('.svg'))
      .toList();

  setState(() {
    someImages = imagePaths;//someimage is a list
  });
}
```