# GridView.builder only returns the last file

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test, dart-pub

I'm, making a pdf reader with asset pdf files and my app only returns the last file. upon clicking other files it gives an error:

`[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)\] Unhandled Exception: Unable to load asset: assets/books/Masud Rana - Durgom Durgo.pdf`

and printing the asset file paths only printed this:

> [assets/books/Masud Rana - Durgom Durgo.pdf

**here is the code:**

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../api/pdf_api.dart';
import 'pdf_viewer.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart' as path;

class AssetBooks extends StatefulWidget {
  const AssetBooks({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State createState() => _AssetBooksState();
}

class _AssetBooksState extends State {
  List assetFilePaths = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getAssetFilePaths();
  }

  void _getAssetFilePaths() async {
    String fileString = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/files.txt');
    List filePaths = fileString.split('\n');
    setState(() {
      assetFilePaths.addAll(filePaths);
    });
    print(assetFilePaths);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    void openPDF(BuildContext context, file) => Navigator.of(context).push(
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => PDFViewerPage(file: file)));

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          actions: [
            ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){print(assetFilePaths);}, child: Text("hi"))
          ],
          title: const Text("Classic Books"),
        ),
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: Container(

              // color: Colors.amber,
              child: GridView.builder(
            physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
            shrinkWrap: true,
            gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
              crossAxisCount: 3,
              crossAxisSpacing: 20.0,
              mainAxisSpacing: 20.0,
            ),
            itemCount: assetFilePaths.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return assetFilePaths == null
                  ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
                  : Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius:
                              BorderRadius.circular(10), // radius of 10
                          color: Colors.green // green as background color

                          ),
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () async {
                            print(assetFilePaths);
                            final path = assetFilePaths[index];
                            final file = await PDFApi.loadAsset(path);

                            openPDF(context, file);
                          },
                          child: Text(path.basenameWithoutExtension(assetFilePaths[index]))),
                    );
            },
          )),
        ));
  }
}
```

here is file.txt:

```
assets/books/Masud Rana - Durgom Durgo.pdf 
assets/books/advs.pdf 
assets/books/Flutter Roadmap.pdf 
assets/books/Mein Kampf Adolf Hitler.pdf 
assets/books/The Da Vinci Code.pdf
```

I expected clicking the button will open the pdf reader. but this just opens on the last file "The da vinci code". I've tried flutter clean but the result is same.

Comment: can you try the accepted answer of this post to get list of files ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56544200/flutter-how-to-get-a-list-of-names-of-all-images-in-assets-directory

Answer (score 0):

Have you added your assets to the pub?

Inside pubspec.yaml:

```
assets:
    - assets/
    - assets/books/
```

Comment: Yes, and they work on other pages.