# Flutter how to specify file path in asset folder

Tags: flutter

I have a sound file in asset folder and I can check if it exist using code like below:

```
    if (FileSystemEntity.typeSync(
        '/Users/admin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/AC8BED2E-4EF1-4777-A399-EBD52E38B5C7/data/Containers/Data/Application/1390EE2C-A5D8-46E0-A414-AAC2B83CD20C/Library/Caches/sounds/3/unbeaten.m4a') !=
    FileSystemEntityType.notFound) {
  print('file is found');
} else {
  print('not found');
}
```

As you can see I need to use the absolute path.  Is there a way to check if the file is in the asset folder using path like 'assets/sounds/3/unbeaten.m4a' without the need to specify the whole path?

Comment: Did you try with the `path_provider` library already?

Comment: Check these two questions... The asset manifest lets you find out the complete list of assets available. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50998573/flutter-how-to-store-and-access-files-with-assetbundle https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56369100/how-do-i-get-an-array-list-filled-with-all-the-image-paths-i-loaded-as-assets-in/56369329#56369329

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned by @frank06, by using path_provider, I am able to check if a file is in asset folder or not by using the following code.  But this works for iOS only and I am still trying to find a solution for Android.  Notice the need to add /Library and /Caches for iOS.  For Android, it seems that I can't see the path unlike that of iOS.

I would appreciate it if anyone could provide me some info for that of Android.  The appDir looks like this for Android - /data/user/0/com.learnchn.alsospeak/app_flutter/

```
directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
var parent = directory.parent;

var directoryPath = directory.path;
var parentPath = parent.path;

String testString = 'sounds/3/unbeaten.m4a';

parentPath = parentPath + '/Library' '/Caches/' '$testString';
```