# Unable to load assets images due to whitespace in image name

Tags: flutter

Hey I have many images in my assets folder and I use the following code to get the list of images

```
...

List<String> imagesList;

 Future _initImages() async {
    final manifestContent =
        await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString('AssetManifest.json');

    final Map<String, dynamic> manifestMap = json.decode(manifestContent);


    final imagePaths = manifestMap.keys
        .where((String key) => key.contains('images/')) // mention folder where all images exists
        .toList();

    print('imagePath ${imagePaths.length}');

    setState(() {
      imagesList = imagePaths;
    });
  }

  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _initImages();
  }

...
```

So the issue is that my images name contains whitespace and while print I imagePaths, I get path something like this

```
' my%20image%20.jpg '
```

which means I think it is unable to count whitespace and when I give this path to Image it gives unable to load assets error. Any solution?

path of one of the image :

```
assets/images/my image.jpg
```

Comment: try renaming images using an underscore in between. Ex: assets/images/my_image.jpg

Comment: what is your flutter version now?

Comment: @ANUPSAJJAN   i cant as number of images are 200+

Comment: @chunhunghan  v1.17.1,

Comment: in pubspec, remove this  "assets/images/my image.jpg", and add only "assets/images/", it will track all images present under the folder "images". And then try getting path, as you are doing in your code.

Have only this : 
assets:
  - assets/images/

remove everything else

Comment: @ANUPSAJJAN   I have already added  ""assets/images/" this. This "assets/images/my image.jpg" I just use to show an example

Comment: can you post a picture of your pubspec once?

Comment: @ANUPSAJJAN I edited my my question you can

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: 
From my understanding you want to remove %20 and replace with a space.

After researching, i have found a better solution

```
String imagePath = "my%20image";

String newPath = Uri.decodeFull(imagePath);
print(newPath) //Prints my image
```

Try it out.

Comment: I think of that too but imagePath is a list. I can convert list to string using toString() but how can I convert string back to list?

Comment: You can loop through all the images and add to list dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

Here the problem is the spaces. If the path is:

> "assets/images/my image.jpg"

Due to spaces you are getting the path as

> "assets/images/my%20image.jpg"

In flutter giving path to Image.asset as

> Image.asset("assets/images/my image.jpg"),

will render the image.

**but Image.asset("assets/images/my%20image.jpg"),**
will throw error.

Hence, before appending all paths to your list, make sure you remove all %20 and then append the path to the list.

For that, you can use https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-core/String/replaceAll.html

Example:

```
String path = "assets/images/my%20myimage%20spacex%20launchAmerica.png";
String newpath = path.replaceAll("%20", " ");
print("NewValidPath is : $newpath");
```

Output:

> NewValidPath is : assets/images/my myimage spacex launchAmerica.png

Now, this is a valid path. Hence this will render the image.

Edit: As per your situation you can do the following:

```
var pathList = manifestMap.keys.toList();
 for(int i=0;i<pathList.length;i++){
      pathList[i]=pathList[i].replaceAll("%20", " ");
 }
 setState((){
    imagesList=pathList;
 });
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you should replace the %20 with space and return the new path. You should make some edits to your code as shown below:

```
final imagePaths = manifestMap.keys
    .where((String key) => key.contains('images/')) // mention folder where all images exists
    .toList();

for(int i=0;i<imagePaths.length;i++){
      imagePaths[i]=imagePaths[i].replaceAll("%20", " ");
 }

print('imagePath ${imagePaths.length}');

 setState((){
    imagesList=imagePaths;
 });
```

You can also try @Julitech suggestion. Loop through the images and add to list dynamically.

```
final imagePaths = manifestMap.keys
    .where((String key) => key.contains('images/')) // mention folder where all images exists
    .toList();

for(int i=0;i<imagePaths.length;i++){
      imagePaths[i]=Uri.decodeFull(imagePaths[i]);
 }

print('imagePath ${imagePaths.length}');

 setState((){
    imagesList=imagePaths;
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys I found the solution and here is my solution and edited function :

```
Future _initImages() async {
    final manifestContent =
        await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString('AssetManifest.json');
    print('Hello $manifestContent');

    final Map<String, dynamic> manifestMap =
        json.decode(manifestContent.replaceAll('%20', ' '));  // Here replacing it 

    print('kHello ${manifestMap.keys}');

    final imagePaths = manifestMap.keys
        .where((String key) => key.contains(
            'assets/images/')) // mention folder where all images exists
        .toList();
    print('hddd ${imagePaths.length}');
    setState(() {
      print('ddd $imagePaths');
      imagesList = imagePaths;
    });
  }
```

Comment: No need to run other separate for loop

Comment: Yes, that is true. I was going to edit my answer but its cool. Glad you solved it.