# How do i access specific folders in android using flutter?

Tags: android, dart, flutter

Say I have folders like movies, ifont, song, images, whatsapp,  etc

On my External  storage,  I want to access files from any of the folders above and store to a list  using flutter.

I already added the necessary permissions to android.xml 
But I am clueless on how to go further from there,
I would appreciate  a code snippet.

Thanks.

Comment: https://flutter.io/assets-and-images/
Please try to make it more clear what you try to accomplish. What do you want to do with the files in the folders? Where do the files come from? What is the problem?

Comment: I want to display images from the specific  folder on an image view.

Comment: Then the link in my previous comment should provide the answers you are looking for.

Comment: Sorry,  but I wasn't talking  about assets. I meant files on my Android device,  think of it like a gallery app,  displaying images on an Android phone..

Comment: My aim is to read this images to a list and display them in my app.  I.e from the user's phone

Comment: You can do that, but you need to list them in Dart code manually. Like `const List<String> images = {'image1': 'assets/images/image1.png', 'image2': 'assets/images/image2.png', 'image3': 'assets/images/image3.png', };` and then you can use `AssetBundle` to load the entries.
There is ongoing work to get this code auto-generated for assets.

Comment: You haven't understood my question yet sir,  i want to get images from the user's phone.  For example images  gotten from camera,  or images downloaded to the user's phone or already on SDcard. I am not talking  about assets. I don't know if I am clear enough now

Comment: You can check image_picker or similar plugins. They are still a bit limited though. You might build your own plugin until better out-of-the-box solutions become available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [listSync](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-io/Directory/listSync.html)  to get the list of sub-directories and files and you will get a list of [FileSystemEntity](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-io/FileSystemEntity-class.html).you also need to get persmmison to external storage so use this [plugin](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/simple_permissions#-readme-tab-)

- check out this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50975636/list-of-files-in-flutter) also