# In Flutter, how can one list available documents?

Tags: list, flutter, document

I've searched through DuckDuckGo/Google, stackOverflow, Github and flutter documentation and plugin repository, but I can't seem to find the answer to this simple question:

How can I list all available documents known to Android/IOS?

the closest thing I could find was a [document picker](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/documents_picker), but that gives me no control over the UI, it takes me to an external Picker

Comment: did you see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51082690/how-do-i-access-specific-folders-in-android-using-flutter/51083514#51083514)

Comment: thanks @RaoufRahiche, I don't think that would work, since, in IOS we don't have access to files in hard-disk, so having disk access wouldn't help me

Comment: thanks for the info i didn't know about that